# Switch between different website languages - documentElement.lang

Tags: javascript

I want to use a `switch` and individually target each English version of the website.

I tried using `en/lang`, but it does not work...

The variable populates a `div` with the string.

I could not use just the `case 'en'` since the English text is different for both SE and NO, so I need to target the English version of SE and NO individually.

```js
switch (document.documentElement.lang) {

  // ------------------------------ SE -----------------------------------    

  case 'en/se':
    var heroTitle = 'This is an se english title';

    break;

  case 'se':
    var heroTitle = 'This is a swedish title';

    break;

    // ------------------------------ NO -----------------------------------  

  case 'no/en':
    var heroTitle = 'This is a no english title';


    break;

  case 'no':
    var heroTitle = 'This is a no title';

    break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into i18next -- its by far the best way to do translations in JS.

https://www.i18next.com/

But to answer your question you'll want the full country code and lang. like `en_US` and `en_SE` I suppose. You can get the user's language with `navigator.language`

Comment: in case of i18next => i18next.resolvedLanguage https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage